# Quicksight breaking up strings for use of all aspects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I was wondering if anyone has every had experience with breaking a string up in quicksight and using certain aspects of the string.  My example is a data set that returns tags like this "animals|funny|dog-park" I have used "split(tags,'|',1)" but then all that gets returned is the first part(animals). I have also tried a combination of ifelse->locate->split with no luck. Is there a way to split these tags to where they are all usable (animals) & (funny) or (funny) & (dog-park), etc.?  Say the article associated will then be broken up into one tag but also another separately?  I know this will end up being a calculated field most likely.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since QuickSight does not support any form of nested fields (including objects and list) in analysis, you need to normalise this into separate rows before feeding the data to QuickSight.

Otherwise, if you leave it as is, you would be limited to filtering using string `contains` and doing string lookup in calculated fields - nevertheless you would not be able to use these tags as categories (such as in colours field well of visuals).

Comment: Thank you, I was kind of wondering if that was the case.